# SQL Conditional Logic to select the 'most appropriate' record

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-schema

I greatly simplified the entire system but it shows enough for my particular question. 
I'm storing in a table information about one photo that has been scaled down several times (maintain its aspect ratio).
I'm trying to devise one query to my table that can get back the most appropriate photo.

**What I mean by most appropriate is**

1. if a request for 705px width then the largest one will be returned in this case 700x394
2. if I request for 50px width then the smallest one will be returned in this case 150x84

Sample Data Photo Resized Dimensions

```
  700x394
  400x200
  300x169
  150xx84
```

**More information**

- The images in the database are all proportionally resized down using a reference edge.
- The reference edge is the longest edge that means if I receive a portrait photo then it gets resized down proportionally to *x700, *x400, *x300, *x150.
- If the image is landscape it gets resized down the same way 700x*, 400x*, 300x*, 150x*

This query partially works from 0 to maximum edge or lower. However it doesn't work if I request a dimension that's over the maximum width.

```
select * from images
WHERE width >= 750
order by width asc
limit 1
```

I also have this working trick to change logic based on portrait or landscape

```
IFNULL(((width >= height AND width >= $length ) OR (width <= height AND height >= $length )), TRUE)
```

I have an SQL Fiddle where I have my question/problem outlined available here

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. I understand I could read in all the data and then do this logic in my back-end language such as PHP but this is on a high demand data pipe and want to minimize overhead.

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91ca9/2

Comment: The part about "What I mean by most appropriate is" is not clear at all. Can you explain in more detail? Is the input to the query always going to be one number, which is the width requested? Also, a single photo will always be resized to 4 different sizes?

Comment: How about selecting  `abs(tableWidth - queryWidth) = min(abs(tableWidth - queryWidth)` or similar for height; that way if you're "over the top" or "under the bottom" you'll get the max or min value in the table... can't imagine that would perform better than PHP though.

Comment: EkoostikMartin  Yes sorry about that, I'm looking for the closest match to what I requested. So if I request 251 and I have 300 and 200 in the database I would ideally like to get back the 300.

Comment: JohnnStrings that's clever!!!!! Thank you I will play with that and compare to PHP.

Comment: My concern with my comment is that "min"is an aggregate function that will scan your table every time you run it, looking for the min value... so if performance is a concern, you may still have issues. (But feel free to 1-up my comment :-) .

Comment: there is no need to use the min function, you can just order by the the abs value width minus the requested dimension and take the top 1. Would definitely still be quicker that puling in the entire data set and running it through php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM images
ORDER BY ABS(width-750) ASC
LIMIT 1
```

using the absolute value of width minus requested dimension it will return you the nearest image size. I'm sure you could adapt this as you need to check height also

Answer (score 2):

What I can infer from your problem is that you want to output the image details which match the nearest lowest value from the `width` if an upper bound doesn't exist. So, the query mentioned below merges both outputs and return them in ascending order. If an upper bound exists it will be returned otherwise the closest lower bound of `width` will be returned. You can play around with the query to suit your need.

```
SELECT id, width, height
FROM
( ( SELECT id, height, width, 750-width AS diff
    FROM images
    WHERE width < 750
    ORDER BY width DESC
      LIMIT 1
  ) 
  UNION ALL
  ( SELECT id, height, width, width-750 AS diff
    FROM images
    WHERE width >= 750
    ORDER BY width ASC
      LIMIT 1
  ) 
) AS tmp
ORDER BY diff asc
LIMIT 1 ;
```

Alternatively you can easily do this in php, by checking if the upper bound query returns `NULL` or not, and accordingly apply the lower bound query. But that's not an option you are looking for perhaps.

--edit: This would work similar to the absolute function but you'll have more control in this to manipulate it as per your need.

Comment: Although more complicated, this should perform much better, assuming there is an index on `width`.